# Foreach in php not working

Tags: php, foreach

I am getting an error

> undefined variable label

I don't know why. I am using a `foreach($labels as $label)`, but its not sending the data into label. I used `var_dump($labels)` and I got a whole array, so the problem doesn't seem to be with `$labels`, why doesn't the `foreach` to `$label` work?

Here is my code:

```
foreach($labels as $label) { ?>
  <tr>
    <td>img src=<?= $label["image"] ?>  </td>
    <td>50 cents</td>
    <td>$<?= $label["quantity"] ?> </td>
    <td>$<?= $label['quantity']*.5 ?></td> 
  </tr>
<? }
```

Here is the var_dump:

```
array(11) { [0]=> array(2) { ["image"]=> string(14) "circles/L3.jpg"    ["quantity"]=> string(2) "72" } [1]=> array(2) { ["image"]=> string(14) "circles/L2.jpg" ["quantity"]=> string(2) "24" } [2]=> array(2) { ["image"]=> string(11) "TAGS/T4.jpg" ["quantity"]=> string(2) "72" } [3]=> array(2) { ["image"]=> string(14) "circles/L3.jpg" ["quantity"]=> string(2) "60" } [4]=> array(2) { ["image"]=> string(15) "circles/L11.jpg" ["quantity"]=> string(2) "72" } [5]=> array(2) { ["image"]=> string(12) "TAGS/T12.jpg" ["quantity"]=> string(2) "72" } [6]=> array(2) { ["image"]=> string(14) "circles/L3.jpg" ["quantity"]=> string(2) "36" } [7]=> array(2) { ["image"]=> string(14) "circles/L3.jpg" ["quantity"]=> string(2) "60" } [8]=> array(2) { ["image"]=> string(14) "circles/L3.jpg" ["quantity"]=> string(2) "36" } [9]=> array(2) { ["image"]=> string(14) "circles/L3.jpg" ["quantity"]=> string(2) "36" } [10]=> array(2) { ["image"]=> string(11) "TAGS/T3.jpg" ["quantity"]=> string(2) "60" } }
```

here is the rest of the code:

```
  $id="";
  if(!empty($_GET['id'])){
 $id=$_GET['id'];
 }


$cs = "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=purimlabels";
$user = "seforim";
$password = '1234';

try {
    $options = [PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION];
    $db = new PDO($cs, $user, $password, $options);
    $query='SELECT  image,quantity  FROM labels WHERE  CustomerID=? AND    Submitted="NO" ';
    $statement = $db->prepare($query);
    $statement->bindvalue(1,$id);
    $statement->execute();
    $labels = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $statement->closeCursor(); 
    }catch(PDOException $e) {
    die("Something went wrong " . $e->getMessage());
   }
```

Comment: How about you show that `var_dump($labels)` you mentioned?

Comment: Please provide the full error message and code that reproduces the error.

Comment: I agree with the posters above, it's hard to tell without seeing your other code...

Comment: At a guess, your error is coming from a different part of your code. The code in your question cannot possibly produce that error message. The full error message will show the exact location of the problem

Comment: @Phil there's a possibility of the code given producing an error if PHP short tags aren't enabled. Aside from that, I tend to agree

Comment: @e_i_pi PHP short-tags have not affected the availability of `<?=` since pre 5.4 though that last line in OP's code *could* be an issue

Comment: Try changing that last line to `<?php }`. It's not safe to rely on the `short_open_tag` config being enabled

Comment: @Phil, that's the one I was talking about, sorry should have been more clear

Comment: here is the var_dump

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you cannot use short tag `<?` on your local environment. Check `short_open_tag = On` value in your local `php.ini` file.

You may use below code with `php` tag, generally short open tags are disabled because they can cause issues reading xml, so i would personally opt for the second option

```
<table>
<?php foreach($labels as $label): ?>
  <tr>
    <td><img src="<?php echo $label['image']; ?>" /></td>
    <td>50 cents</td>
    <td>$<?php echo $label['quantity']; ?> </td>
    <td>$<?php echo $label['quantity'].'*.5'; ?></td> 
  </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works! i just have a small problem: the view is showing ?> from the line" <img src=...?>" how do you fix that?

Answer (score 0):

Try modifying your code to this:

```
foreach($labels as $label) { ?>
   <tr>
   <td>img src=<?= $label["image"] ?>  </td>
   <td>50 cents</td>
   <td>$<?= $label["quantity"] ?> </td>
   <td>$<?= $label['quantity']*.5 ?></td> 
   </tr>
<?php }  // note the change here
```

**Update**

The above works on my machine, but since that did not help, try leaving everything in php and see if you still get the error.  Here's a modified version of your code to try:

```
<?php
    // define $labels as first two elements of your var_dump.
    // using older syntax
    $labels = array(array(
                    "image"=> "circles/L3.jpg",
                    "quantity"=> "72"
                   ),
                array(
                    "image"=> "circles/L2.jpg",
                    "quantity"=> "24"
                  ));

    echo "<html>\n\t<body>\n\t<table>\n";
    foreach($labels as $label) {
       echo "\t\t<tr>".
            "<td>img src=".$label["image"]."</td>".
            "<td>50 cents</td>".
            "<td>$".$label["quantity"]."</td>".
            "<td>$".($label["quantity"]*.5)."</td>".
            "</tr>\n";
    }
    echo "\t</table>\n\t</body>\n</html>";
?>
```

This outputs the following for me:

```
<html>
    <body>
    <table>
       <tr><td>img src=circles/L3.jpg</td><td>50 cents</td><td>$72</td><td>$36</td></tr>
       <tr><td>img src=circles/L2.jpg</td><td>50 cents</td><td>$24</td><td>$12</td></tr>
    </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Hopefully this works; I'll leave it to you to fix up the HTML formatting as necessary/desired.

Comment: Hmm, I'm sorry to hear that.  It makes the difference on my machine when testing this.  I'll update with another option to try.